# atomicCAS: behaviour within a block

Tags: cuda

I am doing some experiments with atomics in CUDA. My big question mark is how do they behave when two threads running in the same block atomically access the same address. I tried some tests with atomicAdd and it worked atomically but when I tried the below code using atomicCAS, the result is not what I expect. Does anybody have an explanation?

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuComplex.h>
using namespace std;
__global__ void kernel(int * pointer)
{
    *pointer=0;
    *(pointer+threadIdx.x+1)=0;
    __syncthreads();
    *(pointer+threadIdx.x+1)=atomicCAS(pointer,0,100);
}
int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
    int numThreads=40;
    dim3 threadsPerBlock;
    dim3 blocks;
    int o[numThreads+1];
    int * pointer;
    cudaMalloc(&pointer,sizeof(int)*(numThreads+1));
    cudaMemset(pointer,0,sizeof(int)*(numThreads+1));
    threadsPerBlock.x=numThreads;
    threadsPerBlock.y=1;
    threadsPerBlock.z=1;
    blocks.x=1;
    blocks.y=1;
    blocks.z=1;
    kernel <<<threadsPerBlock,blocks>>> (pointer);
    cudaMemcpy(o,pointer,sizeof(int)*(numThreads+1),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);



    for (int i=0;i<numThreads+1;i++)
            cout << o[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;

}
```

In the above code atomicCAS running within the same block access the same address to make the compare and exchange... My expectation is that only one atomicCAS will find the value to compare to 0 while all others will find it 100, but strangely the output of my program is:

```
 100 100 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

i.e. all threads found the value to compare to set to 0.

Answer (score 5):

You have reversed the order of the execution configuration arguments. It is `<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>`, not vice versa. So you are launching 40 blocks of 1 thread each, not the other way around.

This is why you get the results you see -- since only one thread is running in each block the last `numThreads-1` values in the array will always be zero.

If I swap the order I get this output:

```
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 0 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

You can see that all threads but one wrote `100`, and one thread wrote `0`, as expected.

Comment: Ahh ....yes stupid mistake of mine.... Let me ask just something very important to me...atomics are atomic in any context or there is some particular situation that they do not work? I remember to have read something somewhere but can't remember:(

Answer (score 2):

You have your threadperblock and blocks variables backwards in your kernel invocation.

Instead of this:

```
 kernel <<<threadsPerBlock,blocks>>> (pointer);
```

Do this:

```
 kernel <<<blocks, threadsPerBlock>>> (pointer);
```

Then you'll get the correct output.

Comment: If the post time wasn't so different, I would assume this was a simultaneous answer... :)